# Deployment in Azure CLI is possible but on azure pipelines, authorization problem exists

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-pipelines

I am using terraform AZ cli on azure portal and azure pipelines. My idea is to create peering with 2 vnets on azure. I've created security vnet, azure ad application, service principal, role definition and assignment, peering both ways, role with permissions

```
["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings/write", "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/peer/action", "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings/read", "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings/delete"]
```

on main vnet and security vnet scope. It works perfect when I do normal deploy using az CLI on azure portal. When I use azure pipelines to deploy that, I have this error:

```
2023-08-14T06:51:21.2948611Z [31m│[0m [0m[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mauthorization.RoleDefinitionsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationFailed" Message="The client '######' with object id '####' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/write' over scope '/subscriptions/<mainvnetsubscriptionhere>/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/######' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."[0m
2023-08-14T06:51:21.2949778Z [31m│[0m [0m
2023-08-14T06:51:21.2950258Z [31m│[0m [0m[0m  with azurerm_role_definition.vnet-peering,
2023-08-14T06:51:21.2950754Z [31m│[0m [0m  on peering.tf line 60, in resource "azurerm_role_definition" "vnet-peering":
2023-08-14T06:51:21.2951248Z [31m│[0m [0m  60: resource "azurerm_role_definition" "vnet-peering" [4m{[0m[0m
2023-08-14T06:51:21.2951586Z [31m│[0m [0m
2023-08-14T06:51:21.2951859Z [31m╵[0m[0m
```

Only difference in code is secret in pipeline variables instead of terraform.tfvars file.
I had an idea that it maybe existing because I didn't use az login on pipelines somehow and maybe I need to authenticate in pipeline, but I think of it rather as a rabbit hole now.
Cheers,
Michał

Deployment on AZ CLI- Succesful
Error on Azure Pipelines - 403 Error
I need to make pipeline work.

Comment: Could you provide more information on which azure pipeline task are u using to run the cli command is it azure cli or something other? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines, simply paste the yaml task and its parameters.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried creating v-net peering by using azure ad app or service principal authentication with Azure Devops Azure CLI task and it was successful, Refer below:-***

**`My main.tf code:-`**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "3.8.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  
subscription_id = "xxxxx6-b4fd-e2b6e97cb2a7"
tenant_id = "xxxxce4-99ed-af9038592395"
client_id = "xxxxx5-b838-6d26a31435cb"
client_secret = "xxxxx-CS0ifbLE"
features {
  resource_group {
    prevent_deletion_if_contains_resources = false
  }
}
}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "peeredvnetsili-rg"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example-1" {
  name                = "petersnetwork1"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example-2" {
  name                = "petersnetwork2"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_space       = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "example-1" {
  name                      = "peers1to2"
  resource_group_name       = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name      = azurerm_virtual_network.example-1.name
  remote_virtual_network_id = azurerm_virtual_network.example-2.id
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_peering" "example-2" {
  name                      = "peers2to1"
  resource_group_name       = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name      = azurerm_virtual_network.example-2.name
  remote_virtual_network_id = azurerm_virtual_network.example-1.id
}
```

**YAML pipeline script:-**

```yaml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'sid subscription'
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      terraform init
      terraform apply -auto-approve
```

**My Azure repository:-**

[image]

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Reference:-**

[azurerm_virtual_network_peering | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_network_peering)